# Extending Boostrap to include extra small inline form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started by using the default bootstrap inline form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="hidden-xs">Quantity</span>
                <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Qty</span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="quantity" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
        <span class="hidden-xs">Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Small to Large:

[image: Small to Large]

Extra Small:

[image: Extra Small]

So I though I would extend bootstrap using to support extra small inline forms:

CSS

```
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .form-group
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .form-group .input-group
{
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Html:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline form-inline-xs">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="hidden-xs">Quantity</span>
                <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Qty</span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
        <span class="hidden-xs">Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

However, I'm missing something as the result isn't inline (as in the first image):

[image]

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/at3259ha/)

Comment: Just to be clear All you want is the inline button with the `+` and `cart` icons right?

Comment: You are correct, it should look no different (other then the text changing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After (what I should have done before posting) looking at the source code, it appears I need more CSS:

```
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .input-group .input-group-addon, 
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .input-group .input-group-btn, 
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .input-group .form-control
{
    width: auto;
}

.form-inline.form-inline-xs .input-group > .form-control
{
    width: 100%;
}
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .control-label
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .radio, .form-inline .checkbox
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .radio label, 
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .checkbox label
{
    padding-left: 0;
}
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .radio input[type="radio"], 
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.form-inline.form-inline-xs .has-feedback .form-control-feedback
{
    top: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could have had the button with no text and just the icons

Comment: Very true.  The business requires a quantity as we do quite a majority of quantity orders.